# C# How to write each table in a Word file to its own Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, ms-office, office-interop

I'm trying to write code in C# WinForms that allows a user to select a directory tree, and extract all of the table data from a word document into an excel file. Presently, the code compiles and you can select your directories, etc, but once it begins to iterate through the loop for each table it crashes.

The program successfully opens the first word file and writes the first excel file (table_1_whatever.xlsx) and saves it in the destination folder. However, on the second table in the same file I get this error on this line of code:

```
    worksheet.Cells[row, col] = objExcelApp.WorksheetFunction.Clean(table.Cell(row, col).Range.Text);
```

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The requested member of the collection does not exist.'

I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't exist. Each time it goes through the foreach loop it should be creating a new worksheet, but it doesn't appear to be working. Any insight, examples, or suggestions are welcome!

Code:

```
    private void WordRunButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var excelApp = new excel.Application();
        excel.Workbooks workbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
        var wordApp = new word.Application();
        word.Documents documents = wordApp.Documents;
        wordApp.Visible = false;
        excelApp.Visible = false;

        string[] fileDirectories = Directory.GetFiles(WordSourceBox.Text, "*.doc*",
               SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var item in fileDirectories)
        {
            word._Document document = documents.Open(item);
            int tableCount = 1;

            foreach (word.Table table in document.Tables)
            {
                if (table.Cell(1, 1).ToString() != "Doc Level")
                {
                    string wordFile = item;
                    appendName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wordFile) + "_Table_" + tableCount + ".xlsx";

                    var workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
                    excel._Worksheet worksheet = (excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];

                    for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 1; col <= table.Columns.Count; col++)
                        {
                            var cell = table.Cell(row, col);
                            var range = cell.Range;
                            var text = range.Text;

                            var cleaned = excelApp.WorksheetFunction.Clean(text);

                            worksheet.Cells[row, col] = cleaned;
                        }
                    }
                    workbook.SaveAs(Path.Combine(WordOutputBox.Text, Path.GetFileName(appendName)), excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault);

                    workbook.Close();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
                }
                else
                {
                    WordOutputStreamBox.AppendText(String.Format("Table {0} ignored\n", tableCount));
                }

                WordOutputStreamBox.AppendText(appendName + "\n");
                tableCount++;
            }

            document.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(document);
            WordOutputStreamBox.AppendText(item + "\n");
        }


        WordOutputStreamBox.AppendText("\nAll files parsed");

        excelApp.Application.Quit();
        workbooks.Close();
        excelApp.Quit();

        WordOutputStreamBox.AppendText("\nExcel files closed");

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
        WordOutputStreamBox.AppendText("\nExcel files released");

        wordApp.Application.Quit();
        wordApp.Quit();
        WordOutputStreamBox.AppendText("\nWord files have been quit");

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(documents);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
        WordOutputStreamBox.AppendText("\nWord files have been released\n");
    }
```

Edit 1:(Sorry for posting in the wrong place the first time!)

Ok, so the problem has been isolated...

The code logic of the code was fine, and the table was in fact there. The issue is that the second table of these files has a set of split cells in it, so, when it reaches the cell that contains it, the program crashes.

As a temp fix, I have just set it to ignore the table if the header == whatever. Does anyone know of a solution that actually allows to extract this data though?

Comment: I'm commenting based on the information you posted in the "answer" (which belongs in your question): It appears your code, in essence, "walks" every cell in the Word table? In that case, try looping the CELLS instead of row-by-column. That usually works in tables with split/merged cells. HOWEVER you need to consider how to write this information to Excel? Possibly, it would make more sense to work with the underlying Word Open XML, which you can "parse" more like HTML ("spans"). Doing everything with Open XML would also be much faster than the interop.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response! Writing to Excel was something that was required by the company I am working for. I was able to write cell by cell to a text file or a csv file, but not to the excel file.

I will try and recreate the code using Open XML if I can! I'm only a few months into programming and am trying to keep up with all of the terminology! Just to be clear, is this what you're referring to?:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Comment: Yes, I use the Open XML SDK. There are other libraries, with which I'm not very familiar, but I get the impression many of those don't support the entire "object model" the way the SDK does. FWIW if you can write cell-by-cell to a text file, then it should be possible to do the same to Excel. OTOH it might be faster to write to a text file then import *that* into Excel - especially if you already have that code. (Not faster in execution than the Open XML, however.)

Comment: Ok! I will try to get some code running using the Open XML and post that alongside the modified code that actually works using the Interop. From there, perhaps some additional insight can be given on how to speed things up because as you have said, the interop is dreadfully slow, and there are about 30,000 files that need to be opened and processed.

Comment: Looks to me like you should move `int tableCount = 1;` up to just before the `foreach (word.Table table in document.Tables)` loop. The way it is now will never increment the value. I'm a bit puzzled about `appendName`.. You build a string there with `appendName = "Table_" + tableCount + "_";`, but do not pass it along to function `ParseTables()`. You DO however use it in that function..

Comment: Yeah, I left a few things incorrect when I posted it initially; I was trying a few different things to try and isolate the bug. I will post the working code for it now.